# Fetching MAX MIN in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, greatest-n-per-group

[Original Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5c398/4)

[Failed attempt](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5c398/12)

[Failed Query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5c398/15)

I need some help on pulling each brand's most expensive and cheapest products in the same row, the result should be like this:

```
BRAND_NAME  EX_PRODUCT_ID   EX_NAME EX_PRICE  CHEAP_NAME  CHEAP_PRODUCT_ID  CHEAP_PRICE
HTC         7               Item G  700       Item A         1                500
Sony        5               Item B  100       Item F         2                10
Nokia       4               Item D  260       Item C         3                250
```

But the following query doesn't match the `MAX(price)`,`MIN(price)` with the corresponding products:

```
BRAND_NAME  EX_PRODUCT_ID   EX_NAME EX_PRICE CHEAP_NAME CHEAP_PRODUCT_ID CHEAP_PRICE
HTC         1               Item A   700     Item A     1                500
Sony        2               Item B   100     Item B     2                10
Nokia       3               Item C   260     Item C     3                250


SELECT t1.brand_name,t1.ex_product_id,t1.ex_name,
       t1.ex_price,
       t2.cheap_name,t2.cheap_product_id,
       t2.cheap_price        
FROM(

  SELECT m.product_id AS ex_product_id,
       m.name AS ex_name,
       MAX(m.price) AS ex_price,
       b.brand_name 
   FROM model m 
   INNER JOIN series s ON s.series_id = m.series_id
   INNER JOIN brand b ON b.brand_id = s.brand_id
   LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT m.product_id,
           m.name,
           MAX(m.price) AS ex_price
        FROM model m   
   )ex ON ex.ex_price = ex_price  /*** problem here*****/
       AND ex.product_id = m.product_id   
   GROUP BY b.brand_id
)t1

JOIN (
  SELECT m.product_id AS cheap_product_id,
         m.name AS cheap_name,
         MIN(m.price) AS cheap_price,
         b.brand_name 
   FROM model m 
   INNER JOIN series s ON s.series_id = m.series_id
   INNER JOIN brand b ON b.brand_id = s.brand_id
   INNER JOIN(
     SELECT m.product_id,
           m.name,
           MIN(m.price) AS ch_price
        FROM model m   

   )ch  ON ch.ch_price = cheap_price   /*** problem here*****/
        AND ch.product_id = m.product_id 
   GROUP BY b.brand_id
)t2 ON t2.brand_name = t1.brand_name


LIMIT 10
```

Can anyone point me on how to match the maximum and minimum prices for each brand back with the corresponding expensive and cheap products? My query obviously isn't able to identify the `MAX` and `MIN` columns in the on clause.

Comment: Your in MySQL, which is pretty much the only reason you're getting this, and not a syntax error - every other major DB throws an error if you include columns in the `SELECT` that aren't in the `GROUP BY` or an aggregate function, for this exact reason.  At least you noticed!  Some people just assume they're seeing the right results....  This is known as a [tag:greatest-n-per-group] problem, which is essentially a solved problem for all dbs.

Comment: You must first find the IDs with Max and Min prices in separate queries (ensuring they only return  IDs and not other non-aggregating fields such as cheap_name). After finding the IDs, join back on such IDs, to get their names etc.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can do this with conditional aggregation.  Just find the minimum and maximum prices in a subquery, and then pull the data out for those:

```
  SELECT b.brand_name,
         minmax.price_max,
         max(case when m.price = minmax.price_max then m.product_id end) as max_product_id,
         max(case when m.price = minmax.price_max then m.name end) as max_name,
         minmax.price_min,
         max(case when m.price = minmax.price_min then m.product_id end) as min_product_id,
         max(case when m.price = minmax.price_min then m.name end) as min_name
   FROM model m INNER JOIN
        series s
        ON s.series_id = m.series_id INNER JOIN
        brand b
        ON b.brand_id = s.brand_id INNER JOIN
        (SELECT m.product_id, m.name,
                MIN(m.price) AS price_min,
                MAX(m.price) AS price_max
        FROM model m   
       ) minmax
       ON m.price IN (minmax.price_min, minmax.proc_max) AND 
          minmax.product_id = m.product_id   
   GROUP BY b.brand_id
```

Note if there are multiple products with the same minimum or maximum price, this pulls out an arbitrary one.  You can get all of them by using `group_concat()` instead of `max()`.

Comment: Gordon,the query isn't working. There's no ex_price column in the table. I changed it to `ON minmax.price_max` but no results yielded. [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5c398/27)

Comment: @RedGiant . . . I fixed the query so the `on` clause uses the right columns.

Comment: I have corrected the typo `proce_max` in the query, but that doesn't help. It doesn't return any result  [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5c398/29).